# Deepcopy does not result in unique objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy, python-3.8

I have a programme which generates a list of somewhat simple dictionary objects like

```
class loginfo:
    info = {
        'global_time': -1,
        'exptime': 0,
        'type': ""
        # omitted other entries for brevity
        }
    def assign(self, d):
        if d is not None:
            self.info.update((key, d[key]) for key in d if key in self.info)
    def __str__(self):
        s = str(self.info['global_time'])
        for key in self.info:
            if key == 'global_time':
                continue
            s += ",\t"
            s += str(self.info[key])
        s += "\n"
        return(s)
```

I read lines from a somewhat weired logfile, parse them in a separate routine `parse_linetype` which returns a single loginfo object. I want to create a list of these objects for further processing before I write the result to a nicer logfile:

```
from copy import deepcopy
output_log = list()
version = -1
global_time = 0
with open(path+in_filename, 'r', errors="ignore") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        log_info = parse_linetype(line, version, global_time)
        output_log.append(deepcopy(log_info))
        # debug print:
        print(i,": ",line, len(output_log), "\n", str(output_log[len(output_log)-1]), str(output_log[0]))
```

Yet this code - to me unexpectedly - returns a list of identical objects even though I deepcopy the object already on appending the list. The objects are returned properly from the parse function - and as an added benefit actually - the info not available in the parsed log line are carried over from the previous log line(s). But that carry-over should NOT influence what is stored in the objects stored in `output_log`.

Where do I go wrong with creating a real, the deepcopy, where do I keep using the reference and why?

Typical output of the debugging print looks currently like this (and see that the parsed lines and returned objects do differ - but always all objects in the output_log are identical. Here the 'AIN' and 'OTHER' are the changed parts in the records - but the first record (thus 2nd line for comparison) should never change of course):

```
6288 :  [10:03:04.546] AIN, 57668, 970, Device handling terminates
 6289 
-1,  56797, AIN

 -1,     56797, AIN


6289 :  57670: Terminating experiment loop
 6290
 -1,     56797, OTHER

 -1,     56797, OTHER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deepcopy doesn't copy classes, only instances. It makes the assumption that any shared class resources are *designed* to be shared, and you made your `info` dictionary a class attribute.

This is what the [`copy` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) says about this:

> This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, socket, window, array, or any similar types. **It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning the original object unchanged**; this is compatible with the way these are treated by the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module.

(Bold emphasis mine).

Move the dictionary to an *instance* attribute instead:

```
class loginfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = {
            'global_time': -1,
            'exptime': 0,
            'type': ""
            # omitted other entries for brevity
        }

    # ...
    # assign and __str__ unchanged.
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I wasn't aware of this difference - a big one though! Thanks for the info